# Custom windows logon interface using pgina

Tags: c#, winforms, winlogon

I know this has probably been asked a thousand times on here but anyway. I'm trying to write a custom logon screen using c#. I am simply wondering if it is possible to write one and possible use pgina to authenticate the user.

Please don't say "don't do it, its not possible, its insecure" or anything like that please. I just want to know if it is possible and would like some help pointing me in the right direction of how to possibly do it.

Comment: Why that would be insecure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pGina you can write C# plugin to authenticate user but you can't change the credential provider (logon interface). Except if you change the C++ code of pGina source.